# Intellisence in IDLE is slow. Is the slowness of python the reason?

Tags: python, python-idle

I am playing with IDLE. But it seems that intellisense in IDLE is a bit slow. When we type `time.` I need to wait a second or more for the intellisense to appear. What is the reason for this? I have heard that IDLE is developed in Python itself and that Python is a bit slower than other languages (slower but not notably so).

Now, is the slowness of Python the reason?

Comment: Python's supposed "slowness" is not the issue here: Python is easily fast enough to do this kind of thing faster than you could notice.

Answer (score 4):

This delay is intentional! IDLE waits for two seconds before popping up the completion window, to avoid having it always pop up when often you just want to continue typing.

This delay is configurable, though currently IDLE does not make changing this easy. To change this:

**EDIT: Recent versions of IDLE allow configuring this easily, see [Terry Jan Reedy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37849395/40076) for details.**

1. Find the `.idlerc` directory in your user directory, e.g. `C:\Users\username\.idlerc` on Windows
2. Inside this directory, create a file named `config-extensions.cfg` if it does not already exist
3. Open this file in a text editor

Add the following to the contents of the file:

```
[AutoComplete]
popupwait=2000
```

The value of `popupwait` is the delay in milliseconds, and the default is 2000. Set this value to whatever you like, such as zero for "as fast as possible".

Comment: pressing tab when there is something other then whitespace to the left of the cursor will also trigger the popup, I find the 2 second wait is perfect when I am blanking entirely but hitting tab is good every other case.

Comment: @taleinat, Thanks a lot. That helped me. And one more question. I have used PythonWin IDE and wrote a script which will show a message box. It uses win32gui module. After that i made an exe from it with Py2exe. But it gave me a bunch of files with the total size of 5.6MB. Python27.dll is most sized file among them. Can i reduce this size ?. And can i combine all this files to one exe file ?. I have tested with Pyinstaller with --onefile command but didn't worked.

Comment: @Goldsmith That's a completely different question! Just open a new question and you'll have a better chance of getting answers.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the exact release you are using, but currently (Since about Sept 2014), IDLE makes changing the popup delay easy.  Select Options and Configure Extensions if you see that choice.  Otherwise select Configure IDLE and then the Extensions tab (since Fall 2015).  In either case, select AutoComplete and change the popupwait.  I happen to have reset to to 0 for myself.  I think 2 seconds is too long, but changing the default is problematical.

Comment: Thanks @Terry Jan Reedy. I solved it by changing config file. And can you please give me a  hint about my above comment.? i.e. regarding to the size of exe

Comment: I can't because I have no experience with either program.